# php select array by path

Tags: php, arrays, object, select

May I get help to know whether this is possible?

I want to select array dynamically.

For instance,

```
$oj = (object)['A' => (object)['B' => (object)['C' => (object)['D' => []]]]]

$E = 'A'
$oj->$E // this will work

$E = 'A->B'  
$oj->$E // this will not work
```

What else I can do except to write a full path? Or maybe please tell me whether this is possible or is there any example I can refer?

```
$oj[A][B][C][D]     <---NO
$oj->A->B->C->D     <---NO

$E = A->B->C->D    
$oj->E              <--What I want   


Question Update: 

$oj->E = 'Store something'  <-What I want, then will store into $oj.

//So E here is not pick up the value of D, but the path of D;
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Looking for this `$oj[A[B[C[D]]]]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explode the path by `->` and trace the object part by part of the path:

```
function getPath($obj,$path) {
  foreach(explode('->',$path) as $part) $obj = $obj->$part;
  return $obj;
}
```

Example

```
$oj = (object)['A' => (object)['B' => (object)['C' => (object)['D' => []]]]];
$E = 'A->B->C->D';
getPath($oj,$E);
```

If you also want to write, you can do it ugly, but simple way using `eval`:

```
eval("\$tgt=&\$oj->$E;"); // $tgt is the adress of $oj->A->B->C->D->E
print_r($tgt); // original value of $oj->A->B->C->D->E
$tgt = "foo"; 
print_r($oj); // $oj->A->B->C->D->E = "foo"
```

Comment: thank you very much, question updated, your example will only pick up the value of D, and what I want is selecting the path

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

Are you possibly looking for [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)? OK, probably not.

In any case you're probably better off writing your own set of classes or functions, e.g.:

```
setUsingPath($oj, 'A->B->C->D', $x);
$x = getUsingPath($oj, $E);
```

But if you're sure what you want is the best solution to the (unspecified) problem and `$E = 'A->B'; $oj->E...` is the syntax to go with, it should be possible with *shudder* [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). A set of recursive *shudder* [`__get()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get)s should do the trick.